# Merge Fields In Email Template Builder

Tags: email-template, merge-field

In Case there are fields like `Contact Phone` `Contact Email` and `Contact Name` I have to use these fields in email template builder but these fields are not showing merge fields so how can I use these fields in email template? Can anyone provide the solution.

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392931&type=1